# Is there any way to linearize x-x^2<=0?

Tags: math

I am trying to solve an optimization problem.
The objective function and all constraints of this problem are linear except x-x^2<=0.
Is there any way to linearize x-x^2<=0, where x is a continuous variable?
Note that x is not in the objective function.

Comment: I think what you want is [Mathematics Stack Exhange](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about practical computer programming but rather belongs on [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/) once the questioner has added more of his own work and explained just where he is stuck.

Comment: Yes, there is a way. You can see that `x - x² <= 0` means `x² >= x` which means `x <= 0` or `x >= 1`

Comment: Way he formatted was a math question, but definitely something that can be solved via MatLab or another programming language. Just wish he restructured the question for code.

Answer (score 1):

The usual approach is to convert the problem to an iterative, non-linear one where you solve for increments:

```
f(x) = x - x^2
df/dx = 1 -2x
```

Make an initial guess x0; take a step for dx; solve for df; calculate x1 = x0 + dx and f1 = f0 + df and iterate until convergence.

You might look into optimization with constraints.  Read up on Lagrange multipliers.